# SVG line animation for dynamic text

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, fonts

I'm trying to implement drawing effect for text from user input so that it looks like it's being written.

Very much like the drawing of "there" on this page: http://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/

Where I'm at: https://jsfiddle.net/w3nmwqgo/1/

SO editor is complaining about no code, so here's the same thing:

```js
var path = document.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];

// this doesn't return true length
var length = path.getTotalLength();

path.style.strokeDasharray = length;
path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  if (length < 0) clearInterval(intervalId);

  path.style.strokeDashoffset = --length;
}, 25);
```

```css
/* shouldn't need this? */
path {
  transform: translate(20px, 100px);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M-7.34 0.29C-7.34 0.22-2.88-6.77 3.24-14.54C11.38-24.84 18.79-31.82 24.70-34.78C24.77-34.85 34.49-39.60 39.89-35.14C41.26-33.98 41.90-32.62 41.98-30.96C42.41-23.69 34.27-17.28 29.88-11.81C26.35-7.42 24.98-4.32 25.63-2.45C25.99-1.37 27.00-0.65 28.51-0.50C36.22 0.22 45.50-6.34 56.88-15.91C57.17-16.13 57.17-16.56 56.95-16.85C56.74-17.14 56.30-17.14 56.02-16.92C49.10-11.09 44.14-7.42 39.96-5.04C35.42-2.45 31.82-1.44 28.66-1.80C27.14-2.02 27.00-2.66 26.93-2.81C26.64-3.67 26.71-5.76 30.89-11.02C33.26-14.11 35.78-16.63 35.78-16.63C36.58-17.42 43.63-24.62 43.27-31.03C43.20-33.05 42.12-34.92 40.68-36.07C39.24-37.22 37.51-38.02 35.42-38.23C33.84-38.45 32.04-38.30 30.02-37.94C26.78-37.22 24.19-36.00 24.12-35.93C20.74-34.27 16.92-31.32 12.74-27.22C9.43-23.98 5.90-20.02 2.23-15.41C-0.43-12.02-2.74-8.78-4.61-6.19C-0.50-14.76 4.97-23.47 10.22-31.10C14.47-33.91 22.54-39.31 30.67-45.50C40.90-53.35 48.02-59.98 51.98-65.30C52.06-65.45 54.79-69.26 53.14-72.72C52.63-73.73 51.70-74.59 50.62-74.95C49.32-75.38 47.81-75.24 46.15-74.45C44.71-73.73 41.33-70.70 36.94-66.02C32.04-60.91 26.42-54.43 21.24-47.95C16.92-42.55 12.89-37.22 9.29-32.04L8.93-31.54C7.34-29.16 5.76-26.86 4.25-24.55C-1.44-15.62-5.76-7.42-8.50-0.29ZM49.10-73.94C50.62-74.02 51.70-72.94 51.98-72.14C53.28-69.41 50.98-66.17 50.90-66.10C42.84-55.15 22.03-40.54 12.31-33.98C15.98-39.17 19.44-43.70 22.25-47.09C33.84-61.56 44.28-72.14 46.73-73.30C47.81-73.80 48.38-73.94 49.10-73.94ZM59.04-0.94C65.59 2.59 77.26 0 83.74-2.38C91.66-5.62 98.35-9.00 107.78-16.99C108-17.28 108.07-17.64 107.86-17.93C107.57-18.22 107.21-18.22 106.92-18.00C97.78-10.15 91.01-6.70 83.30-3.53C79.20-1.87 66.10 1.58 59.76-2.02C51.62-6.48 57.67-20.02 62.14-24.26C62.78-23.98 63.58-23.62 64.44-23.26C67.68-21.89 72.94-20.16 79.20-19.87C85.32-19.58 93.31-22.03 96.70-27.79C101.16-35.35 93.24-40.90 85.32-39.89C78.77-39.02 71.71-35.50 65.23-29.23C64.08-28.08 62.86-27.00 61.85-25.92C60.34-26.64 59.47-27.22 59.47-27.22C59.18-27.43 58.75-27.36 58.54-27.07C58.39-26.78 58.46-26.35 58.75-26.21C58.75-26.14 59.54-25.63 60.91-24.91C55.66-19.44 50.33-5.69 59.04-0.94ZM63-25.27C64.01-26.35 65.09-27.36 66.02-28.30C74.09-35.78 79.99-37.87 85.54-38.66C92.45-39.67 99.29-34.70 95.62-28.51C92.95-24.05 85.68-20.88 79.20-21.17C73.15-21.46 68.11-23.11 64.94-24.41ZM110.74 0.65C112.25 0.65 114.12 0.50 116.06-0.07C128.38-3.60 136.08-8.28 145.66-15.55C145.94-15.77 145.94-16.20 145.73-16.49C145.51-16.70 145.08-16.78 144.79-16.56C135.43-9.36 127.80-4.97 115.78-1.37C111.96-0.22 107.86-0.14 105.62-2.59C103.39-5.11 104.98-9.65 104.98-9.65C105.98-12.31 107.21-15.05 108.58-17.86C120.02-25.63 130.97-33.77 136.44-38.59C141.41-42.98 146.38-48.46 150.05-53.50C153.07-57.74 156.67-63.58 156.31-67.82C156.17-69.55 155.45-70.85 154.08-71.71C152.42-72.79 150.26-72.79 147.67-71.64C145.73-70.85 143.57-69.34 141.12-67.25C137.09-63.79 133.78-59.76 133.78-59.69L133.78-59.69C133.70-59.62 128.09-52.34 121.61-42.62C115.70-33.62 107.35-20.38 103.75-10.15C103.68-9.94 101.88-4.82 104.62-1.73C105.91-0.22 107.86 0.65 110.74 0.65ZM134.78-58.90L134.78-58.90C134.93-59.04 138.10-62.93 141.98-66.31C145.51-69.34 150.34-72.58 153.36-70.63C154.37-69.98 154.94-69.05 155.02-67.68C155.23-64.73 153.14-59.98 149.04-54.29C145.37-49.25 140.47-43.92 135.58-39.60C130.54-35.14 120.31-27.50 109.80-20.23C113.76-27.94 118.66-35.78 122.69-41.90C129.10-51.41 134.57-58.68 134.78-58.90ZM149.11 0.65C150.62 0.65 152.50 0.50 154.44-0.07C166.75-3.60 174.46-8.28 184.03-15.55C184.32-15.77 184.32-16.20 184.10-16.49C183.89-16.70 183.46-16.78 183.17-16.56C173.81-9.36 166.18-4.97 154.15-1.37C150.34-0.22 146.23-0.14 144-2.59C141.77-5.11 143.35-9.65 143.35-9.65C144.36-12.31 145.58-15.05 146.95-17.86C158.40-25.63 169.34-33.77 174.82-38.59C179.78-42.98 184.75-48.46 188.42-53.50C191.45-57.74 195.05-63.58 194.69-67.82C194.54-69.55 193.82-70.85 192.46-71.71C190.80-72.79 188.64-72.79 186.05-71.64C184.10-70.85 181.94-69.34 179.50-67.25C175.46-63.79 172.15-59.76 172.15-59.69L172.15-59.69C172.08-59.62 166.46-52.34 159.98-42.62C154.08-33.62 145.73-20.38 142.13-10.15C142.06-9.94 140.26-4.82 142.99-1.73C144.29-0.22 146.23 0.65 149.11 0.65ZM173.16-58.90L173.16-58.90C173.30-59.04 176.47-62.93 180.36-66.31C183.89-69.34 188.71-72.58 191.74-70.63C192.74-69.98 193.32-69.05 193.39-67.68C193.61-64.73 191.52-59.98 187.42-54.29C183.74-49.25 178.85-43.92 173.95-39.60C168.91-35.14 158.69-27.50 148.18-20.23C152.14-27.94 157.03-35.78 161.06-41.90C167.47-51.41 172.94-58.68 173.16-58.90ZM193.54 0.72C196.56 0.72 200.16-0.22 203.90-2.23C207.43-4.10 211.18-6.91 214.78-10.22C216.14-11.52 217.51-12.89 218.81-14.33C222.34-10.58 227.66-9.00 232.99-9.50C237.53-9.94 241.99-11.88 246.10-15.05C246.38-15.26 246.38-15.62 246.17-15.91C245.95-16.20 245.52-16.27 245.23-16.06C236.95-9.50 226.22-8.64 219.67-15.34C221.04-16.85 222.34-18.50 223.49-20.09C225.86-23.47 227.52-26.50 228.10-28.58C228.17-28.87 228.96-32.04 227.66-33.48C227.23-33.98 226.66-34.34 226.01-34.49C226.15-34.70 226.15-34.99 226.01-35.28C225.94-35.35 224.42-37.44 220.97-38.66C218.95-39.38 216.58-39.60 214.13-39.46C211.18-39.24 208.01-38.38 204.48-36.86C200.38-34.99 195.55-31.61 191.59-27.79C188.28-24.55 183.96-19.51 182.45-13.68C182.45-13.46 180.94-7.56 184.03-3.31C185.83-0.86 188.78 0.50 192.82 0.72ZM215.71-38.23C217.44-38.23 219.24-37.87 220.46-37.51C222.91-36.79 224.50-35.06 224.86-34.63C224.50-34.63 224.14-34.63 223.70-34.56C222.05-34.27 220.46-33.34 219.24-31.82C218.09-30.46 217.30-28.58 216.79-26.50C216.22-23.90 216.22-21.10 216.79-18.65C217.08-17.50 217.51-16.42 218.09-15.48C216.72-13.97 215.35-12.53 213.84-11.16C206.28-4.10 198.65-0.22 192.89-0.58C189.29-0.72 186.70-1.94 185.11-4.03C182.38-7.78 183.74-13.32 183.74-13.32C186.26-23.26 197.93-32.54 204.98-35.64C208.87-37.37 212.62-38.23 215.71-38.23ZM224.86-33.34C225.65-33.34 226.30-33.12 226.66-32.69C227.45-31.75 227.02-29.74 226.87-29.02C226.01-25.70 222.98-21.17 218.95-16.49C217.51-19.30 217.37-23.11 218.02-26.21C219.02-30.67 221.54-33.26 224.86-33.34Z"
  />
</svg>
```

Now, obviously no one can draw like that (unless they're an octopus).

The issue is with the path, but I cannot find an alternative way to achieve this. Inkscape, perhaps? Anyway, the path is generated by: https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-to-svg, using the League Script font from: http://www.quillingpatch.com/2015/01/31/list-of-free-single-line-fonts-for-rhinestones-pensmarkers/. text-to-svg does the job, but it doesn't suit this purpose. Some other issues:

- League Script is supposed to be a single line font, but it seems that it uses fill. I've looked into Hershey fonts, engraving fonts, yet I haven't found something that would generate a path appropriate for animated drawing.
- `path.getTotalLength` returns a length that is much longer than the actual length as the drawing is completed much earlier than when `length` reaches `0`. Most likely caused by the way the path is.
- The path needs to be translated by arbitrary values as it contains negative values (as in the CSS above). Would there be a better way to fix this than by parsing through the data to find the lowest negative X and Y values and then translating it by that amount?

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the stroke-dashoffset http://css-shapes.xyz/text-drawing-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said, the font you are using only *appears* to be a single line.  But it is actually not.  The paths in the characters go around the boundary of the font glyphs

This will be true of all fonts.  So any text-to-svg utility will not work for you.

You will almost certainly have to convert the SVG to the suitable format yourself.  Load your converted SVG into Inkscape (or your favourite vector editor) and manually trace the shape of each of your letters with single (non-filled) paths.

You will then have an SVG that will work with dash-offset animation.

Comment: Manually trace the shape as in draw with hand? I'm not very familiar with Inkscape, but is there no way of having it convert the above form of paths to just stroke paths automatically?

Comment: Not really.  Finding the "skeleton" of an arbitrary filled shape is quite a hard problem.

Comment: If it is true of all fonts, then why do I keep coming across Hershey, single-line, or engraving fonts that are defined as having no fill? Haven't read too much into it, but the contradicting info has left me confused. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was talking about modern vector fonts like TTF etc.  If you can find an SVG version of a Hershey font that suits your needs, then great.  Note however that not all Hershey fonts are single stroke.  They commonly use several strokes to represent fatter parts of the character. Plus not all browsers support SVG fonts.  You may need to extract the glyph paths from the font and arrange them manually on the page yourself.